# To Get the model class name of a given contoller class MVC3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a number of controller classes of which I don't know the Model class or Context class How to get the Model and Context class name of any given Controller Class?

Comment: Show code.it is not clear what you want to do

Comment: Just want to know if there is a way to know the context class of a given controller.